# Proof verification for Heine-Borel: a closed and bounded set is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Is my proof valid?

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and bounded, then it is compact.

*Proof*. We will prove by induction.
Consider the base case $A_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^1$.
Then by the Heine-Borel Theorem in $\mathbb{R}$, $A_1$ is compact.
Now assume the hypothesis for $A^\prime \subset \mathbb{R}^{n -1}$ and denote the set as
\begin{align*}
    A^\prime = A_1 \times A_2 \times \dotsc \times A_{n-1}.
\end{align*}

We must show that $ A = A^\prime \times A_n$ is compact.
Note that $A_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact by the argument above. Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ contained in $A$, written as $a_n = (b_n, c_n)$, where $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is contained in $A^\prime$ and $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is contained in $A_n$.

By the compactness of $A^\prime$, there exist a subsequence $(b_{n_j})$ that converges to a limit in $A^\prime$.
Similarly, there exists another subsequence $(c_{n_{j_i}})$ that converges in $A_n$. Then $(a_{n_{j_i}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $A^\prime \times A_n$. Hence, $A$ is sequentially compact and thus compact. By the principle of mathematical induction, a closed and bounded set is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whenever $n \geq 1$.

**QED**

Comment: "Then by the Heine-Borel Theorem in R, A1 is compact"  Are you sure you alllowed to use that.  Isn't that what you are attempting to prove?  I dont think the issue has anything to do with the dimensions of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I am attempting to prove that Heine-Borel can be generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$, given that it holds in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: One big problem is that not every set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is actually of the shape $A_1 \times \dots \times A_n$ with $A_i \subset \mathbb{R}$. Consider for example $[0,2]^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and remove from it the square $[0,1]^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and you'll see that the resulting set is not a product of sets in $\mathbb{R}$. This may make induction an unfeasible method...